# select specific values from json & convert into bash variables

Tags: json, bash, select, jq

I'm new to jq, I have the following JSON & I need to extract FOUR values i.e. SAUCE_KEY, sauceKey, SAUCE_VALUE, sauceValue etc. And I need to covert these bash variables as i.e.

```
SAUCE_KEY=sauceKey
SAUCE_VALUE=sauceValue
```

If I will echo it, it should print it's value ie. echo $SAUCE_KEY

I have used the code as:

```
jq -r '.env_vars[] | with_entries(select([.key] | inside([".env_vars[].name", ".env_vars[].value"])))' | jq -r "to_entries|map(\"\(.value)=\(.value|tostring)\")|.[]"
```

By doing so, i was able to get values as
name=SAUCE_KEY, value=sauceKey and so on.

```
{
  "@type": "env_vars",
  "env_vars": [
    {
      "@type": "env_var",
      "@href": "/repo/xxxxx/env_var/xxxxx",
      "@representation": "standard",
      "@permissions": {
        "read": true,
        "write": true
      },
      "name": "SAUCE_KEY",
      "value": "sauceKey"
    },
    {
      "@type": "env_var",
      "@href": "/repo/xxxxx/env_var/xxxxx",
      "@representation": "standard",
      "@permissions": {
        "read": true,
        "write": true
      },
      "name": "SAUCE_VALUE",
      "value": "sauceValue"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If instead of trying to extract variable names from the JSON, you populate an associate array with the names as keys, it's pretty straightforward.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A sauces
while IFS=$'\001' read -r name value; do
    sauces[$name]=$value
done < <(jq -r '.env_vars[] | "\(.name)\u0001\(.value)"' saucy.json)

for name in "${!sauces[@]}"; do
    echo "$name is ${sauces[$name]}"
done
```

prints out

```
SAUCE_VALUE is sauceValue
SAUCE_KEY is sauceKey
```

Comment: thanks, after your answer i guess i'm just one step away from final solution, can you please clarify on the followings:
1. JSON that pasted above in my question, get it from Curl response in bash then saved into var but let me know how can I save it to json file i.e. saucy.json

2. Facing the issues:
* env-var.sh: 14: env-var.sh: declare: not found (I guess for "declare -A sauces")
* env-var.sh: 17: env-var.sh: Syntax error: redirection unexpected (I guess due to symbol as "< <")

Comment: @AbidRana Sounds like you're not using bash, or maybe a really old version.

Comment: Oh, and `curl whatever > saucy.json`. Or avoid a file and feed curl's JSON output directly to jq: `curl whatever | jq -r 'whatever'`

Comment: You recommended solution works perfactly well on my win10 (GNU bash, version 4.4.19(2)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)). I'm just wondering, if you know how can I have updated/same version in Tracis ci?